# gema omniauth facebook no retorna toda la información

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gemfile

Al no poner las opciones que se ven más abajo `omniauth` devuelve la información normal de Facebook pero necesito toda la información(género, primer y segundo nombre, email...)

Lo único que devuelve en información extra es el `nombre` y el `id`.

Así lo llamo:

```
auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]

session[:omniauth] = auth
```

**omniauth.rb**

```
provider :facebook, 'key', 'key', {:scope => 'email', :info_fields => 'email,name,first_name,last_name,gender', :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_file => Rails.root.join("cacert.pem").to_s}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todo lo que pides se puede obtener mediante el juego de permisos `public_profile`. El problema es que solo estas indicando `email` y eso no va incluido en el set de datos que proporciona dicho parámetro. [(Facebook ref.)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-public_profile)

Por tanto lo que tienes que modificar es el valor de `:scope` e indicar tambien `public_profile`.

`provider :facebook, 'key', 'secret', {:scope => 'email, public_profile',  :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_file => Rails.root.join("cacert.pem").to_s}}}`

Esto debería funcionar. Y recuerda sacar por consola la respuesta de facebook para saber lo que estás recibiendo desde su API.